# AWS with Xcode 8 beta: Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, sdk

I just tried building an app I was previously developing under Xcode 7 with the new Xcode 8 beta and get the following error with the newest AWS SKD (2.4.5):
`Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21`

Deleting all Frameworks from Embedded Frameworks gets rid of the error, but produces a new one:
`bash: /Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gmsydrrvmebbiuarunefhhwwkuty/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/AWSCore.framework/strip-frameworks.sh: No such file or directory`

Is anyone experiencing similar errors in Xcode 8 and possibly has a fix?

Comment: Did you confirm this file is present "strip-frameworks.sh"

Comment: It is not present. If I put it there manually I get the first error again when compiling.

Comment: So there is issue in that file and the version.

Comment: So I’ll have to wait for amazon to publish a new version (because the old one simply does not work with the new Xcode)?!

Comment: Did you try my answer below?

Comment: Well, no, sorry. I am not using Realm, so I don’t understand how thats relevant? I will out the `AWSCore.framework` back into the Derived Data folder and run your terminal command real quick.

Comment: Nope, still get the first error (Mach-O header).

Comment: Are you using Swift?

Comment: Yes. Didn’t update the project to 3.0 yet though, still on 2.3.

Comment: Check my edited answer and try that?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Swift, I am however not using Swift pods. The project is downloaded from AWS Mobile Hub and already contained all the .framework files. I simply deleted the older versions and updated to 2.4.5 manually.

Comment: The support for Xcode 8  for AWS framework will be supported once its available GA

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swift pods, add this to your Podfile and then check:

```
post_install do |installer|  
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|  
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|  
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'  
        end  
    end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I never got the error building or running, but when I try to validate my app for submission, I've been getting:

> 2016-09-10 01:35:11 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items
>   with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an
>   unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=} 2016-09-10 01:35:11
>   +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header
>   code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}

There are many users that have been afflicted with this issue:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5598
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50969

If you use cocoapods, there are currently 2 things you should try:

1: Disabling ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES in your Podfile as [error2007s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285944/1570970) has recommended.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Remember to run `pod install` afterwards.

2: Changing your `Pods-[YOUR_APP_NAME]` Mach-O Type from a static library to dynamic library.

- Go to your Pods project and under Targets, locate your `Pods-[YOUR_APP_NAME]`.
- Select `Build Settings` and filter by `mach`
- You should now see a `Mach-O Type` set to Static Library
- Change that to Dynamic Library
- Archive your project and try to validate again

Do note that whenever you run `pod install` again, it'll revert that back to a Static Library.